# How do I recover a MariaDB database deleted by renaming to same name different case in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I had a MySql database named (say) "dbname" on my 10.1.13-MariaDB, and used the 'rename' operation in my PHP My Admin 4.5.1 to rename it to "dbName". Unfortunately this deleted the database.

I presume this is because I am running xampp on Windows, and this always creates databases with lower case characters, so the rename created a new database named "dbName", copied the old "dbname" database, then deleted "dbname", which unfortunately translated to deleting the NEW database due to the 'always use lower case for db names' rule.

I understand the cause of this is, at its root, the case insensitivity of Windows, and I have had trouble with this when referring to databases as "dbName" on Linux systems, but when I migrate the database to a Windows system, I need to refer to the database as "dbname" in my php mysqli connections.

However, my question is: can I get the database back! Is there a secret feature that I don't know about where phpmyadmin's rename feature actually MOVES stuff it deletes to somewhere?

I anticipate several comments about the necessity of backups, and I am glad to provide people with the opportunity to remind the community of the importance of frequent backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with how phpMyAdmin handles renaming a table; I've opened a bug report at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13800 and it's already been fixed for inclusion in the next version of phpMyAdmin later this month. Unfortunately, there's no recycle bin or any sort of safety measure here. If you have filesystem-level backups, you might be able to replace your entire MySQL data directory in order to regain access to your database, but unless I'm misunderstanding something it's no longer in MySQL/MariaDB.